# T-SQL find rows with dates in correct order

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to somehow mark the rows for each Class-number in the example below that have a row with the same date or rows with dates in order of each other. Have tried to accomplish this way to long but really have nothing of value to share with you...

Having the following sample data:

```
Date                      Class
2016-10-17 00:00:00.000   1
2016-10-20 00:00:00.000   1
2016-10-18 00:00:00.000   1
2016-10-25 00:00:00.000   1
2016-10-19 00:00:00.000   2
2016-10-19 00:00:00.000   2
2016-10-28 00:00:00.000   2
2016-10-25 00:00:00.000   3
```

With the logic above, it should produce:

[image]

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking... what is "Mark" and why are some 1 and others 0?

Comment: Show us what you have tried. We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: Apply both `LAG/LEAD(Date) over (PARTITION BY Class ORDER BY Date)` and compare to the current date if it's the same or +/1 one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.

```
drop table if exists dbo.test_table;
go
create table dbo.test_table(
  [Date]        date not null,
  Class         int not null)

insert dbo.test_table([Date], Class) values
('2016-10-17',1),
('2016-10-20',1),
('2016-10-18',1),
('2016-10-25',1),
('2016-10-19',2),
('2016-10-19',2),
('2016-10-28',2),
('2016-10-25',3);

select tt.*,
       iif(datediff(day, tt.[Date], lead([Date]) over (partition by Class order by [Date])) in (0,1), 1, 0)+
       iif(datediff(day, lag([Date]) over (partition by Class order by [Date]), tt.[Date]) in (0,1), 1, 0) Marked
from dbo.test_table tt;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you want conditional logic on the results of window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when count(*) over (partition by class, date) > 1
             then 1
             when lag(class) over (partition by class order by date) = dateadd(day, -1, date)
             then 1
             when lead(class) over (partition by class order by date) = dateadd(day, 1, date)
             then 1
             else 0
         end) as mark
from t;
```